# Can I make make touch events pass through a layer?

Tags: javascript, touch, dom-events

I'm making a JavaScript game where the goal is to tap animals. When you do it right I show a bonus layer with stars on top of the animal, but the stars also capture touch events when they are visible. Is there any way to make touch events pass right through the stars to the animal below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, set up `pointer-events: none;` on the stars, and they will act as they're invisible to pointer (and touch) events.

Comment: stopping propagation will ensure click-through? I would think it only stops the event from propagating.

Comment: @JanDvorak Of course, I guess I didn't think that one through :)

Comment: Excellent. Now that I had this to search for I was able to find this example that explains it and has some working code. This solved my problem.
http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/22/css-pointer-events-to-allow-clicks-on-underlying-elements/